# List all 1 numbers that differ in exactly 1 digit

Tags: r

Lets say I have a number:

```
a<-11121
```

I would like to list all other numbers of length `a` that differ in exactly 1 digit. 
In addition assume that the values can only take 1 and 2

The desired solution would be:

```
21121
12121
11221
11122
11111
```

Comment: yes, sorry I added it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some solutions:

**1)** `replace_ith` replaces the ith digit in `a` with 1 if it's a 2 and 2 if it's a 1.  Apply that to each digit:

```
replace_ith <- function(i, a) {
  ch <- strsplit(as.character(a), "")[[1]]
  ch[i] <- if (ch[i] == "1") "2" else "1"
  as.numeric(paste(ch, collapse = ""))
}

a <- 11121
sapply(1:nchar(a), replace_ith, a)
```

giving:

```
[1] 21121 12121 11221 11111 11122
```

**2)** Here is a second possible implementation of `replace_ith`:

```
replace_ith <- function(i, a) {
  a <- as.character(a)
  substr(a, i, i) <- if (substr(a, i, i) == "1") "2" else "1"
  as.numeric(a)
}
```

**3)** Here is a third implementation.  The three terms are the digits before the ith digit times `10^i`, the reversed ith digit times `10^(i-1)` and the digits after the ith digit:

```
replace_ith <- function(i, a) {
  (a %/% 10^i) * 10^i + 10^(i-1) * ( 3 - (a %% 10^i) %/% 10^(i-1) ) + a %% 10^(i-1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer done purely numerically and vectorised as a single line:

```
(2 * a %/% (b <- 10^(1:5))) * b +
  ((2 * a) %% (b / 10)) +
  0.3 * b - a
```

It works by zeroing out each digit of `2 * a` in turn and putting in 3 instead which will flip from 2 to 1 or vice-versa. It does create a variable `b` to shorten the code slightly. This could be removed by either replacing each `b` with its definition or by calling the expression within `local()`.

Here's another using the pipe operator from `magrittr` and matrices:

```
a %>% as.character %>% strsplit("") %>%
  unlist %>% as.numeric %>% matrix(5, 5) %>%
  `diag<-`(., 3 - diag(.)) %>% t %>% `%*%`(10 ^ (4:0))
```

And here's a neater version of the second using purely numeric methods:

```
a %>% rep(5) %>% outer(4:0, function(x, y) x %/% (10 ^ y) %% 10) %>%
  `diag<-`(., 3 - diag(.)) %>% `%*%`(10 ^ (0:4))
```

And another using binary and using package `R.utils`:

```
as.character(a) %>% strsplit("") %>% {.[[1]] == "2"} %>%
  multiply_by_matrix(2 ^ (4:0)) %>% bitwXor(2 ^ (4:0)) %>%
  intToBin %>% as.integer(.) + 11111
```